# Can two players without compatibility mod play borderlands 2 together online coop?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2, xbox-network

Can we both play together without other online players in Borderlands 2 if we **both** do not have the compatibility pack ?

Comment: Why would you not have the compatibility pack?  You're obviously online, so you're able to download it, and it's free.

Comment: Because some items for the regular 4 characters will be replaced with DLC characters, hence reducing the chance of finding loot for current characters.

Comment: Is the occasional mod or character skin that big of a deal?  The drop rates for those are so low to begin with that personally, it's not something I'd be concerned with.

Comment: @MBraedley Yes it is, and everyone is entitled to their own opinion. My friends and I get their drops over 80% of the time when we play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried it and it did not work.

> > If you do **NOT** have the compatibility pack, you can **NOT** play online at all, even with xbox live friends.